# Open Atrium permission issue

Tags: users, distributions

I've added new roles and give it to them a permissions to create content and for some content... and fields but not work with open atrium.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're using the general drupal roles and permissions rather than the organic_groups ones.  Start by reading https://www.drupal.org/node/2340349, and then if you are still stuck, clarify exactly roles and permissions you've been modifying.